# Ogni scarrafone è bello a mamma soja

Tags: idioms, regional

***“Ogni scarrafone è bello ‘ a mamma soja”***

> - Questo detto viene usato quando una donna esalta la presunta avvenenza del proprio figlio, bellezza che poi, in genere è totalmente assente. Sta ad indicare come un figlio, bello o brutto che sia, agli occhi della madre, è sempre perfetto ed incantevole.
> - Per tale ragione viene usato ‘o scarrafone, animale sgradevole, vestigio del brutto e dell’orrido, in particolar modo nella cultura partenopea. Agli occhi di mamma scarafaggio però il cucciolo è e sarà sempre un animale perfetto, gradevole, amabile.
> - In senso più ampio il detto viene usato per esprimere il concetto che qualsiasi cosa appare bella al proprio creatore.

- Esiste il corrispettivo in italiano, o quale modo di dire più si avvicina a questo detto popolare napoletano?

Comment: La forma italiana di 'sto adagio napoletano è “Ogni coleottero è una gazzella agli occhi di sua madre”.

Comment: Non riguarda i figli, ma più in generale la soggettività della bellezza: "la bellezza è nell'occhio di chi guarda". Pare che sia una citazione, ascritta fra gli altri a Goethe (erroneamente, pare). Esiste in tutte le lingue ("the beauty is in the eye of the beholder", "die Schönheit ist im Auge des Betrachters", ecc.)

Comment: @WalterTross - si, ma non solo,la soggettività della bellezza. Qui  il significato è molto preciso riguardo a chi questa 'bellezza' la crea e per cui gli manca l'oggettività del giudizio.

Comment: No, spiacente, non l'ho mai sentito.

Comment: Si usa una italianizzazione: "Ogni scarrafone è bello a mamma sua"
Sempre usato così perché non saprei mettere gli accenti del dialetto. Cmq si usa molto più frequentemente nel terzo esempio riportato che non nei primi due.

Comment: @Josh61: Please, please, please, quando si cita da qualche sito o libro, bisogna mettere la fonte.